# What is the derivative of $g_T(s) = \int_0^T f(t)e^{-st}dt$, where $f(t)$ be locally integrable and bounded?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $f(t)$ be a locally integrable and bounded function defined for all $t \geq 0$. Suppose that
$$
g_T(s) = \int_0^T f(t)e^{-st}dt,
$$
where $\Re(s) > 1$.

In the paper I read the author says that $g_T(s)$ is clearly entire. However, I can not see this. For instance, what is the derivative of $g_T(s)$?

Comment: Under some conditions, you can interchange a derivative and an integral. Read up Lebesgue's "differentiation under the integral". This can be done in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is $\int_0^{T} (-t) f(t) e^{-st} dt$. This is finite because $|\int_0^{T} (-t) f(t) e^{-st} dt| \leq \int_0^{T} T|f(t)|dt$. ($|e^{-st}|=e^{-t \Re s } \leq 1$).